# prefix' is a 32-bit installation, it cannot support 64-bit applications

Tags: 20.04, wine, 64-bit, 32-bit

I installed again (because I had to format my whole PC) Adobe Illustrator CC 17 but when I run it from the terminal it appears: `wine: '/home/victor/.illustratorCC17/prefix' is a 32-bit installation, it cannot support 64-bit applications`. and when I run clicking in the icon nothing happens, is there any tip to fix this issue?

This is the link where I downloaded Illustrator: https://github.com/Gictorbit/illustratorCClinux

Comment: Have you installed Wine? If so, how?

Comment: Yes, i have wine installed here: ```wine-7.8 (Staging)```, when this issue occurred I uninstalled it through: ```sudo apt-get --purge remove wine``` and to install I followed this tutorial: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

Comment: As usual, users should avoid installing from 3rd parties when the package exists in the official repositories.

Comment: Do you say about install wine from their official website, don't you?

Comment: No, the exact opposite actually. Wine exists in Ubuntu's repositories and that should be the default installation almost always. The exception is when a given software only works with the very latest version but even in that very specific case it's better to install the PlayOnLinux tool and then use it to manage containers ("bottles") that can have different Wine versions.

Comment: I uninstalled now again Wine using ```purge``` command and removing his directories, now I have checked and I realized exactly it that Wine already comes with Ubuntu as default without the need to install from 3rd parties, and now I have installed PlayOnLinux tool also

Comment: and the shell script line where the issue occurs is: ```wine64 "$SCR_PATH/IllustratorCC17/IllustratorCC64.exe"```

Comment: I have solved the issue here now, I have uninstalled all the wine folders and directories through autoremove, purge and remove commands and reinstalled it through his tutorial on github! Now it's working